# What is a "clob" or Character Large Object?

Tags: postgresql, terminology, sql-standard

I see in [this post on `listagg` — Rows to Delimited Strings](https://modern-sql.com/feature/listagg) talking about SQL's `LISTAGG()` clause `ON OVERFLOW`

> The return type of `listagg` is either `varchar` or `clob` with an implementation defined length limit.

I've never previously seen the term `clob` before. PostgreSQL doesn't alias anything to it,

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( a clob );
ERROR:  type "clob" does not exist
```

Looking it up, it's apparently a term "character large object" that comes from the spec? What exactly is a "Character Large Object" and how does it relate to the PostgreSQL [`text` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Colloquially

The `clob` in reference here is **NOT** in reference to the spec, which is confusing. This is term [`clob` here is from Oracle/DB2/Informix parlance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_large_object)

- in [SQL Server the CLOB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-advanced-data-types?view=sql-server-2017) type is documented as `text` or `varchar(max)`
- in [Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00172.1510/html/iqlob/CHDGEFBH.htm) it's defined as `LONG VARCHAR` or `clob`
- in [IBM Informix](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_107.htm#ids_sqr_107) it is `clob`.
- in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm) it is also `clob`.

So yes, in this case the PostgreSQL equivalent is `text`, which is confirmed by [this post](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3C7FBE3D.206%40xythos.com) on the PostgreSQL mailing list.

## "Character Large Object" - SQL Spec

But in the SQL Spec, there is some confusion as the terms means something different. The *SQL:2011 Part 1: Framework (SQL/Framework)* defines two types for character string types.

> A "character string type" is either of **fixed length**, or of **variable length** up to some implementation-defined maximum.
>
> - A value of *character large object type* is a string of characters from some character repertoire and is always associated with exactly one
>     character set.
> - A *large object character string* is of **variable length**, up to some implementation-defined maximum that is probably greater than that of other character strings.

So both of the lengths are undefined by the spec, and left to the implementation. But only the "Large Object Character String" is "of variable width".

It goes on to say in Part 2,

> A *character large object type* is a character string type where the name of the specific character string type is CHARACTER LARGE OBJECT. A value of a character large object type is a *large object character string.*

And has one final clarifying mention

> The data types CHARACTER, CHARACTER VARYING, and CHARACTER LARGE OBJECT are collectively referred to as *character string types* and the values of character string types are known as *character strings*.

Which seems a bit confusing, but the spec defines what a `large object character string` can do it `4.2.3.4 Operations involving large object character strings`. They can be used in,

- `<null predicate>`.
- `<like predicate>`.
- `<similar predicate>`.
- `<position expression>`.
- `<comparison predicate>` with an `<equals operator>` or `<not equals operator>`.
- `<quantified comparison predicate>` with the `<equals operator>` or `<not equals operator>`.

But they can **not** be used in,

- predicates other than those listed above and the `<exists predicate>`
- `<general set function>`.
- `<group by clause>`.
- `<order by clause>`.
- `<unique constraint definition>`.
- `<referential constraint definition>`.
- `<select list>` of a `<query specification>` that has a `<set quantifier>` of DISTINCT.
- `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, and `EXCEPT`.
- columns used for matching when forming a `<joined table>.`

In summary, perhaps PostgreSQL doesn't use `clob` as a term anywhere because it's connected with implementation and capabilities and is part of the LO infrastructure which involves SQL Locators. In PostgreSQL the text type is stored in line. That distinction likely doesn't matter much today, as I don't see any of the RDBMs, except [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28393/adlob_tables.htm#i1006887), documenting `clob` as being out-of-line.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something but I don't see where in the cited parts of the spec it says that CLOB is fixed-width. "Fixed length" is explicitly mentioned only in relation to "character string type" in general, irrespective of its size (large or not). Could you clarify what made you interpret the spec as saying the CLOB type is fixed length/width?

Comment: @AndriyM that was not correct, I'm still working through this myself. Reading the spec is pretty close to torturous.

Comment: I wouldn't claim to be great at reading and understanding specs at all times but in this specific case I don't see a problem so far. A *large object character string* is defined as "a value of a character large object type" and is explicitly said to be of variable length. I would take that to mean that a "character large object type" is supposed to imply variable length. Just a suggestion, for what it's worth.